# SQL Java SELECT

Tags: java, sql, select

Самый простой вопрос по SQLite, так как только начал изучать - как составить query для чтения всех имен с двух таблиц. Есть таблица - mentors и applicants,  обе таблицы имеют поле first_name, хочу считать все имеющиеся в двух таблицах first_name.

Пробую так:

```
public static void load() {

    try {

        st = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT mentors.first_name, applicants.first_name FROM mentors, applicants";

        rs = st.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()) {

            System.out.println(rs.getString("first_name"));
        }
            rs.close();
            st.close();
            conn.close();
```

Но отображается неверно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT first_name FROM mentors  
UNION  
SELECT first_name FROM applicants;
```

Такой запрос не то, что вам нужно?

Comment: то что надо, что в таком случае делал мой запрос?

Comment: Ваш запрос делал вывод перекрестного соответствия двух полей. Аналогично записи `SELECT mentors.first_name, applicants.first_name FROM mentors CROSS JOIN applicants`